# _TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double?')

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm facing this issue on flutter... The error is -

> _TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double?')

here is the code :

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 CustomButton(height,width,radius,buttonText,{color}){
  return Container(
    height: height,
    width: width,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
      color: color,
      border: Border.all(
        color: Colors.grey
      )
    ),
    child: Text(buttonText),
  );
}
```

Comment: add more code snippet for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indicate the correct types of the parameters of your function, like

```
CustomButton(double? height, double? width, double radius, String buttonText, {Color? color}){
```

Some extra information:

Not indicating a type makes it a `dynamic`. When you pass a number to a dynamic variable it automatically turns it into an `int`. Your code then tries to pass that int to the constructor of `Container` as `width` for example but that one requires a `double?`. So that will cause an error. By stating your parameter is a `double?` as well you make sure that any numbers passed to it will be doubles. Consider this example:

```
void main() {
    test1(1);
    test2(1);
}

void test1(i) {
  print(i.runtimeType);
}

void test2(double? i) {
  print(i.runtimeType);
}
```

`test1` prints `int` and `test2` prints `double`